# checking pair value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

here i wanna ask about how to check the data in the array if not same value/data on next index, push it on new array,

here is the example:

```js
function check(arr){
  let text = "";
  let newArr = [];
for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length-1 ; i++){
  if(arr[i] !== arr[i+1]){
    text = arr[i] + ' and ' + arr[i+1];
    newArr.push(text)
  }
}
return newArr
};

console.log(check([ 'A', 'A', 'M', 'Y', 'I', 'W', 'W', 'M', 'R', 'Y' ])) 
// output "A and M", "A and Y", "I and W", "W and M",  "R and Y"]
console.log(check([ 'a', 'b', 'j', 'j', 'i', 't' ]))
```

my result here is not i want, it was repeated the data which i already push . in newArr

i want the `ouput` like this :

```
["A and M", "A and Y", "I and W", "W and M",  "R and Y"]
```

because of each array not the same initial,

i hope this question makes sense

Comment: don't understand the result

Comment: Please explain your expected output properly.

Comment: the output is above @xianshenglu

Comment: Update your code `for(let i = 1 ; i < arr.length ; i++){
    if(arr[i] !== arr[i-1]){
      text = arr[i-1] + ' and ' + arr[i];
      newArr.push(text)
    }
  }`

Comment: What would the expected output be for `['A', 'A', 'M', 'A', 'E', 'D']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following :

```js
function check(arr) {
  let text = "";
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0, next = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (next == 2) {
      next = 0;
      i += 2;
    }
    if (arr[i + 1] !== undefined) {
      if (arr[i + 2] !== undefined) {
        text = arr[i] + ' and ' + arr[i + 2];
      } else {
        text = arr[i] + ' and ' + arr[i + 1];
      }
      newArr.push(text)
    }
    next += 1;
  }
  return newArr
};

console.log(check(['A', 'A', 'M', 'Y', 'I', 'W', 'W', 'M', 'R', 'Y']))
console.log(check(['a', 'b', 'j', 'j', 'i', 't']))
```

Comment: the another `A` dissapear

Comment: the result i want in that newArr is the initial which are not same

Comment: the output i want is ``["A and M", "A and Y", "I and W", "W and M",  "R and Y"]``

but your output is . `[
  "A and A",
  "A and M",
  "I and W",
  "W and W",
  "R and Y"
]`

Comment: @ZumDummi it is, do check

Comment: what is the next for ? can we use bollean on it

Comment: @ZumDummi the next is used to check whether the 4 simultaneous values in the array are used or not, if they're used then we loop over the next 4 values. You can't use Booleans on them.